# When a fixed-width <td> expands to fit its content, the other <td>s of that same width expand proportionally as well (using CSS)

Tags: html, css

Suppose I care a great deal about proportional appearances, and want all of my table's `<td>` to have the exact same width. I would specify the width as below:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="25%">
    <td width="25%">
    <td width="25%">
    <td width="25%">
  </tr>
</table>
```

Let's assume the table width is `100px` so each `<td>` should be `25px` wide.

Now suppose that there is unfortunately a really long word in a `<td>` that forces the width to extend beyond its allocated 25%. Let's say this word forces the single `<td>` to take up `40px`.

**When this happens, is there a way in CSS to make it so that now all the `<td>`s will have width `40px`? Therefore fulfilling my requirement that all the `<td>`s have the same width?**

**Other considerations**

- If the screen width is `100px` to begin with, and all the `<td>`s have to be pushed to `40px`, then in this case I want the table to scroll horizontally, so that the table's full width is `160px`
- Given above requirement, `word-break:break-word` doesn't solve the overall problem, since applying it to the table would force the `<td>`s to hold their `25px` width. Also don't like this solution because sometimes words are broken up in a way that's difficult to read

Comment: What about Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Grid layout.

```css
table {
  /* Prevent table width from shrinking */
  width: max-content;
}

tr {
  display: grid;
  /* Use 4 columns of equal width */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

td {
  padding: .2em;
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>abracadabra
    <td>b
    <td>c
    <td>d
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: hmmm... this just created a mess lol. all the content is now verticalized. does this require certain version of CSS?

Comment: Working with 2nd table on this page: https://www.lastmingear.com/gear-info/backpack. As you can see, the TDs are used to define the spectrum, so it imperative that they stay the same width. On smaller screens, the some TDs expand due to content, but to keep the spectrum the same, they should all expand

Comment: The code I posted will work in modern browsers, but (probably) not IE.